# SQL UPDATE Command

Tags: c#, sql

Question. I'm trying to use SQL to update a listview in C#. Using the Query Builder I can do a select, update, insert and delete. Ive got my select but I'm trying to get my update to work with no luck.( I want to use the update button on the listview to update the record) I need some insight as I think I'm writing it wrong. Thanks

```
 UPDATE       SF1411
 SET  ( ItemNumber, QuoteNumber, Item, Descp, Route, Unit, QTYOH, EXTQTY, CSTCD, 
      PCOST, SCOST, ACOST, TCOST, ICOST, Date, BIZCODE, DeleteItem)   
  =  SELECT [ItemNumber], [QuoteNumber], [Item], [Descp], [Route], [Unit], [QTYOH], 
     [EXTQTY], [CSTCD], [PCOST], [SCOST], [ACSOT], [TCOST], [ICOST], [Date], [BIZCODE],   
    [DeleteItem] 
    FROM [SF1411] WHERE ([QuoteNumber] = @QuoteNumber)
```

Comment: can use post a small C# sample code and the error that occurs?

Comment: What does MSSQL say when you execute this SQL directly?

Comment: could we see the C# and the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct your update command is wrong.

you need to tell value of each column rather than just fire a select command.

Answer (score 2):

Im sorry if I understand you wrong, but shouldn't an update statement look like this..

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set individual values like below:

```
UPDATE SF1411
SET ItemNumber = SELECT [ItemNumber] FROM [SF1411] WHERE ([QuoteNumber] = @QuoteNumber);
```

Mostly this is used to update a specific value or if using select in set then it used to select from different table like:

```
Update table set column= "value" where condition;
```

or:

```
Update table set column = select column from tbl where condition;
```